# How to convert scientific notation to text from excel to sql server in correct value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am very frustrated with this problem since yesterday. Example of my excel source is look like this

ID_NUMBER: `7.8103E+11`

Correct Value: `781031145917`

When I use this sql to convert while load into sql server, the value become round up as `781031145920`

```
CAST(CAST(CONVERT(FLOAT,IDNO1) AS DECIMAL(25,0)) AS VARCHAR)
```

This is customer ID, so it must convert to exactly number, cannot be round up or down, can anyone help me on this? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You should look into excel file and change column format into 'text'

Comment: but its client provided sources, I could not simply request them to change it. Additional this is monthly sources, it will auto run monthly, impossible I change it to text format every month.

Comment: Floats support 15 digits of precision, those ID_NUMBERs seem to be only 12 digits. Set the format in Excel to non-scientific and check if it's really storing the right value.

Comment: How are you loading in the file? Your source file might be rounding already, but if you're loading results into i.e. a temp table, your loss of precision could occur there. Atm we only see the conversion statement, but no information about your source (IDNO1). So anything at this point is simply guess work.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
CAST(CAST(IDNO1 AS FLOAT) AS bigint)
```